# Drupal: user account is limited yet receiving workflow updates?

Tags: drupal

Is there a way in the Drupal interface to exclude a specific user from workflow status without having to eliminate his account and make a new one?

Looking over his account, he does not have any of the roles to receive status but he does.

Alternatively, I'd rather be able to somehow search for his actual email in the entire system and make sure he is not listed anywhere. Is that even possible in Drupal?

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on how the workflow status and notifications are configured?

Answer (score 0):

I had to just remove his extra account. He had an older account as a admin buried deep in the users.